# Не выполняется условие if при выборе radio

Tags: php, if

Срабатывает условие в Else, хотя в if указан value = male

```
Пол М:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Ж<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><br>

if ($_POST['gender']=='male') {
    echo "text";
}
else{
    echo "text2";
}
```

Comment: Ем, а вы сам пост то отправляете? Он может срабатывать иза того что пост = null потому елсе, для начала проверьте на емпти пост.

Comment: @UKRman имя ведь передает, когда ставлю == срабатывает if, когда === срабатывает else

Comment: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Нужен контекст кода, возможно в нем проблема. (action формы, название текущего файла).

Comment: @splash58 print_r выводит: Array ( [surname] => Иванов [name] => Петр [gender] => Высшее [vopros] => on ) Уважаемая Иванов Петр

Comment: @Borislav добавил код

Comment: у вас пол не заполняется по умолчанию, и не проверяется на обязательность заполнения. Вот он у вас и пустой

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, вы правы. я идиот :)